# Sublime Text 3 is converting underscored function with camelcase name

Tags: sublimetext3

Im using the latest version of Sublime Text 3. My problem is everything I'm trying to save my work, sublime is converting the name of the function that has underscore to CamelCase text.

Before:

```
my_function_name()
```

After:

```
MyFunctionName()
```

which is causing error. I'm not sure whats causing this.

Comment: Sublime doesn't do this by default, so it's most likely a third party package or plugin that you have installed. Does it do this for files of only a specific type?

Answer (score 0):

Already solved this issue. The problem is cause by installed package named phpfmt.